# How to deal with interface inheritance and common properties?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to design a generic caching system that takes keyed items and allows either read-only or read-write access to a cached version of it. The read-only backing interface is:

```
public interface IReadableItem<TKey>
{
  TKey Key { get; }
}
```

However, I need to be able to dynamically update the key of my writable items. I've come up with two options, but both are unappealing.

I can forgo the inheritance:

```
public interface IWritableItem<TKey>
{
  TKey Key { get; set; }
}
```

... but this leaves me in a situation where I have to specify that every class is both an `IWritableItem` and an `IReadableItem` in order to allow read-write access.

On the other hand, I can use the `new` keyword to override the underlying inheritence:

```
public interface IWritableItem<TKey> : IReadableItem<TKey>
{
  new TKey Key { get; set; }
}
```

... but this leaves me with a bad code-smell, especially when attempting to explicitly implement the interface at the class level.

Is this a situation where I should just take the lesser of two evils, or is there a Third Way?

Comment: Why don't you have a third interface `IKeyItem<TKey>` which declares the key. Your interfaces would then be `IReadableItem<TKey> : IKeyItem<TKey>` and `IWriteableItem<TKey> : IKeyItem<TKey>`.  This will allow you to have readable, and writable classes without the complexity of having to `new` Key.  I think this will clean up the code smell you are sensing.

Comment: @JeffVanzella: The issue is that `IReadableItems` should not be able to `set` the value of the `Key`, so moving it to a third interface doesn't actually address the issue.

Comment: This is a design question and should be posted on [Programmers](http://Programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Maybe the setter is private in the class?  Then you could have a Method `UpdateKey(TKey key) which could do some checking: i.e. they key isn't already set, then set the key through the private setter.

Comment: @JeffVanzella: I was hoping to keep using properties... this definitely feels more like a property than a method. Regarding the Programmer's comment, is there a way to migrate questions?

Comment: An admin will have to migrate it for you.  The process has already been started.

Comment: Mutating identifiers is usually a bad idea.  Is there a reason the key itself would need to change?

Comment: @Dan-Lyons: The key is a property of the item. When the item is added to a collection then the id of that item is set so that it guaranteed to be unique within the collection.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce: that doesn't really say why it needs to change over time.  Why can't the key be set in the constructor?  If you're adding already-constructed objects, a better solution might be to eliminate the key from the base object and compose it in a different type with a key, like KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>.

Comment: @DanLyons: I understand your concern. Assume that this is any property but key. I removed the other properties as they didn't add any complication to the project. The key property itself will be removed and its functionality externalized to a KVP... but imagine there's a property called "Name". My original concern extends for that property as well.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to use inheritance, but have only setter in `IWritableItem`:

```
public interface IReadableItem<TKey>
{
    TKey Key { get; }
}

public interface IWritableItem<TKey> : IReadableItem<TKey>
{
    new TKey Key { set; }
}
```

This still works as expected:

```
class Foo<T> : IWritableItem<T>
{
    public T Key { get; set; }
}
```

It also has the advantage that you can't implement the getter for `IWritableItem` differently from the getter for `IReadableItem`.

Comment: The drawback here is that if you pass a method an `IWritableItem<T>` then it can only access the `Key.set`, and not the `Key.get`.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce You're right, I didn't think of that.